# Character encoding error!

Tags: php, xpath, character-encoding, domdocument

I try get the content this URL: http://www.chromeball.com, but the character encoding is not good.

I have this code:

```
$url = 'http://www.chromeball.com';
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);


$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($data);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);  
$nodes = $xpath->query('//text() | //@alt | //@title | /html/head/meta[@name="description"] | /html/head/meta[@name="keywords"]');
foreach($nodes as $node) {
  $textNodeContent .= " ".$node->nodeValue;
}

$enc = mb_detect_encoding($textNodeContent,'iso-8859-2,iso-8859-1,utf-8');
print  iconv($enc,'utf-8//TRANSLIT',$textNodeContent);
```

But this not working. The character encoding is wrong. How can i convert the $textNodeContent to utf-8? Thanks.

Comment: Please elaborate on 'encoding is wrong'. Also, according to a quick test, the page is served in utf8.

Comment: The mb_detect_encoding($textNodeContent,'iso-8859-2,iso-8859-1,utf-8') return iso-8859-2.
When i print the $textNodeContent, dont display correctly.

Comment: Why are you `iconv()` ing in the first place? The encoding should already be utf-8 from the start.

Comment: No, not utf-8, the mb_detect_encoding($textNodeContent,'iso-8859-2,iso-8859-1,utf-8') function return iso-8859-2. In the meta tag i can write anything, the real encoding is different.

Comment: Check my answer. That worked for me most times.

Comment: @turbod: As Pekka says, if the content is already UTF-8, you don't need to convert it to UTF-8 with `iconv`. Character encoding detection is different to outputting the text.  Are you sending the output to a web page, a console, a file, or something else?

Comment: Ok, but what do i do with this, i just want to write to one webpage, but not displayed correctly?

Answer (score 0):

From the comments on the [mb_detect_encoding](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-detect-encoding.php) page, it looks as though the function is not particularly reliable.  Chrigu (see post dated 29-Mar-2005 03:32), suggests placing `UTF-8` as the first character encoding in the list:

```
$enc = mb_detect_encoding($textNodeContent,'utf-8,iso-8859-2,iso-8859-1');
```

I've tried it, and it now shows the content as being UTF-8.  However, I've just tried it with ISO-8859-1 content, and it detects that as UTF-8 too...

Comment: Thanks, but when i try print the content, dont display correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Initialize DOM like this:

```
$dom->loadHTML('<?xml encoding="UTF-8">' . $data);
```